# Is it possible to have an AWS RDS alert directly

Tags: amazon-web-services, alert, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.3

I'm new to AWS, started working since last couple of months.
A requirement from the client is,

```
Get the daily count of `users` table from `AWS RDS` in an alert at 7 am pacific.
```

I can write a python script to do this and can run it from the aws instace by setting up a CRONJob or A lambda and cloud-watch schedule.

But I've heard from the client that there is something in the AWS (OR AWS RDS) which allows

1. To run an SQL (or a sequel ;)) Query
2. And send that query result in an email alert

He added that one of our colleague had done it for some other purposes (And sad part is colleague has left our org now :( ).

So I'm curious what he might have done directly from AWS or from RDS to send an alert notification.

Please suggest if anyone could have any idea on it.

Answer (score 3):

Writing the query in a lambda function and using either SES or SNS to send the notifications is how I would do it - and either of those options would be doing it 'in AWS'.

Depending on the flavor of RDS you are using (SQL Server Aurora, Postgres etc), there may be a vendor specific way as well, but personally I'd still choose the lambda / cloud watch event method.